# The selector works similarly to /deep/

Tags: css, xpath, css-selectors

I need a selector that will select everything in the X class, except for the Y class objects. Maybe my problem would solve the selector /deep/ but it is not supported.

I have a page structure:

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span class="y"></span>
                <div>1</div>
                <label class="y"></label>
                <div>
                    <span class="y"></span>
                    <p>2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="y"></span>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

I need a selector or xpath that will select:

```
<div>1</div>
<p>2</p>
<div>3</div>
<div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>6</div>
```

I need a general solution.

Comment: It would be beneficial to anyone who wants to help you to perhaps give an example or two of what we need.

Comment: Thanks to the right note, I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//div[@class="x"]//*[not(@class="y") and not(.//*[@class="y"])]
```

will select all `div[@class="x"]` descendants that do not have a `@class="y"` attribute and do not have any descendants that have `@class="y"` elements,

```
<div>1</div>
<p>2</p>
<div>3</div>
<div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>4</div>
<div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
```

which matches your example if we assume that your example was incomplete.

Comment: Thank you, but it's perfectly like pointing out exactly the elements that I wrote.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped and ask a new question regarding CSS.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`:has(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class but it cannot be used in stylesheets for performance reasons. This limitation is baked into CSS engines for all browsers because every time they render web pages, they traverse through the entire DOM and apply selectors that match the existing element (and hence haven't yet looked at their children). Instead this pseudo-class is typically used for dedicated selector engines such as [Sizzle](https://sizzlejs.com/) (known by its development/use for jQuery).

If you wanted to use that pseudo-class, then you could try `:not(.y):not(:has(.y))`. Then in order to get the topmost results, I select children only of elements that did not match (ie. `:has(.y) > :not(:has(.y))`). The one caveat comes if an element with class "y" has children. The only way to handle that is to repeat the pseudo-class specifying `:not(.y)` for as many levels deep that you want to go (I didn't do this). Here's a live example:

```js
// The selector
var elements = $('.x > :not(.y):not(:has(.y)), .x :has(.y) > :not(.y):not(:has(.y))');

// Format the HTML
var html = elements.map(function(){
    var dirty = this.outerHTML;

    // Get leading whitespace to remove
    var leading = (dirty.match(/\r?\n *(?= {4})/) || ['\r\n'])[0];
    // Create regex to replace whitespace
    var leading = new RegExp(leading.replace(/\r/,'\\r?').replace(/\n/,'\\n'), 'g');
    // Show newlines, whitespace in HTML
    var cleaned = $('<div>').text(dirty).html().replace(leading, '<br/>').replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');

    return cleaned;
}).toArray();

// Add the HTML to the page
var results = $('#results');
for(var i=0; i<html.length; i++) {
    results.append($('<li>').html(html[i]));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Sample HTML -->
<div class="x">
    <div class="y"></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span class="y"></span>
                <div>1</div>
                <label class="y"></label>
                <div>
                    <span class="y"></span>
                    <p>2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="y"></span>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>

<h3>Results</h3>
<ol id="results" class="y"></ol>
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, but I wanted a universal solution, saved in the form of the CSS selector itself. Here I need to know the depth of the structure to build a suitably complex selector, that's not the point.

Comment: @KamilTomaszJarmusik The selector is this one: `.x > :not(.y):not(:has(.y)), .x :has(.y) > :not(.y):not(:has(.y))`. If you're saying that elements with class `.y` will have children and that's what you're referencing in terms of depth, then please update your question to show such. Right now this achieves exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: "I need a general solution." I'am need a general selector that solves the problem without knowing how deep the structure is without javascip